# UITableView update when core data changes using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController to populate a UITableView, which works fine. I also implemented all delegate methods for the NSFetchedResultsController (just as described here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

While the table is shown, a number of asynchronous requests update the underlying core data objects which cause the table to refresh/redraw, although not necessary, as the updated core data fields are not displayed.

My question would be: is there a possibility to only update the table cell when certain core data fields of the entity are updated instead of all? E.g. can I set up the NSFetchedResultsController for a certain set of entity attributes?

Thanks! Nek

Answer (score 0):

one of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods is `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`
you could check the object which was changed and update the tableview only if needed

Comment: Thanks! I looked at this, and for test purposes, I don't do anything for change type NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate within that methode. This leads to some weird behavior in the view. Quite some cells are not displayed anymore, but clickable and it's not a smooth scrolling while the objects are getting updated in the background.